# CSS styling not working on android mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Designed a simple webpage that is mobile responsive. The css file loads on desktop view, and on the ios, but does not load the style on mobile android devices.
Tested on vivo 1610 and on the Samsung S20. Tried different solutions nothing seems to be working.

Ignore this i'm just trying to beat the algorithm.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc efficitur arcu at efficitur volutpat. Nunc quam diam, tristique et nulla at, facilisis malesuada ligula. Nulla nec est ac neque scelerisque porta. Duis sed nisl condimentum, feugiat ipsum et, tristique nisl. Nullam in euismod neque. Morbi fringilla odio sit amet tortor malesuada, vel vulputate lacus consectetur. Ut vitae feugiat magna.

```css
@import url("css/style.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap');

a:link,
a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: auto;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

}

/** Mobile devices 480px  **/

@media (min-width: 375px) {
    body {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        background-color: #020f21;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        color: #fff;
        width: 375px;
        margin: 0px 20px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 {
        background-color: #020f21;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 3;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    .grid-container-0 ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .grid-container-0 ul a {
        display: block;
        /* outline: 1px solid white; */
        padding: 5px 40px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 800;
        /* border-right: 1px solid white; */
    }

    .grid-container-0 ul a:hover {
        background-color: #031939;
        ;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .logo {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .navBar {
        clear: both;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .hamburger {
        padding: 25px 25px;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .hamburger .navIcon {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        height: 2px;
        width: 25px;
        position: relative;
        transition: background .2s ease-out;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .hamburger .navIcon {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        height: 2px;
        width: 25px;
        position: relative;
        transition: background .2s ease-out;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .hamburger .navIcon:before {
        background-color: white;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .hamburger .navIcon::after {
        background-color: white;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        top: -10px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .menu-btn {
        display: none;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .menu-btn:checked~.navBar {
        max-height: 240px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .menu-btn:checked~.hamburger .navIcon {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .menu-btn:checked~.hamburger .navIcon:before {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        top: 0;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .menu-btn:checked~.hamburger .navIcon:after {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        top: 0;
    }

    #header1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    #header2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #paragraph1 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px 10px;

    }

    .btn2 {
        font-family: "EB Garamond", sans-serif;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #0062b8 !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .grid-item-1-container img {
        width: 375px;
        height: 310px;
        padding: 30px 0px;
    }

    #image2 img {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 30px 0px;
    }

    #sizer {
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .carousel-control-next {
        display: none;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev {
        display: none;
    }

    .grid-item-4 img {
        display: none;
    }

    #item5 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #item5 h5 {
        font-size: 26px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #item5 p {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #storeIcons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #googlePlayIcon i {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #appleStoreIcon i {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #storeIcons i {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}

/** iPads, Tablets 768px  **/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        background-color: #020f21;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline;
    }

    #text {
        color: aliceblue;
    }

    .grid-container-0 li {
        float: left;
    }

    .grid-container-0 li a {
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .navBar {
        clear: none;
        float: right;
        max-height: none;
    }

    #navbar {
        display: flex;
        gap: 100px;
        font-size: 24px;
        /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }

    #header1 {
        margin: 200px 20px 20px 40px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.08;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #paragraph1 {
        margin: 10px 20px 20px 30px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.65;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #header2 {
        margin: 10px 20px 20px 40px;

        text-align: left
    }

    a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .btn2 {
        font-family: "EB Garamond", sans-serif;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #0062b8 !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .btn2:hover {
        font-family: "EB Garamond", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #fff !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;

    }

    .grid-item-1-container img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .grid-item-1 {
        background-color: #031939;

    }

    .grid-item-3 {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0px 80px;
    }

    .grid-item-1-image {
        /* padding: 10px; */
        height: 600px;
        width: 500;
    }

    #image2 img {
        width: 800px;
        height: auto;
    }

    #caroselControl {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px;
    }

    #cursor1 {
        width: 32px;
        height: 13px;
        margin: 0 16px 0 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    #cursor2 {
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
        margin: 0 17px 0 17px;
        opacity: 0.3;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .grid-item-4 img {
        display: block;
    }

    #item5 {
        display: flex;
    }

    #column1 {
        flex: 1;
    }

    #storeIcons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 10px;
    }
}

/** Small screens, laptops  1024px  **/
/** Desktops, large screens  1200px  **/

@media (min-width: 1150px) {
    body {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        background-color: #020f21;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline;
    }

    #text {
        color: aliceblue;
    }

    .grid-container-0 li {
        float: left;
    }

    .grid-container-0 li a {
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }

    .grid-container-0 .navBar {
        clear: none;
        float: right;
        max-height: none;
    }

    #navbar {
        display: flex;
        gap: 100px;
        font-size: 24px;
        /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }

    #header1 {
        margin: 200px 20px 20px 40px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.08;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #paragraph1 {
        margin: 10px 20px 20px 30px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.65;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #header2 {
        margin: 10px 20px 20px 40px;

        text-align: left
    }

    a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .btn2 {
        font-family: "EB Garamond", sans-serif;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #0062b8 !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .btn2:hover {
        font-family: "EB Garamond", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #fff !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        /* grid-auto-columns: 60% 40%; */
        /* grid-template-rows: 700px 500px 300px; */
    }

    .grid-item-1-container img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .grid-item-1 {
        background-color: #031939;

    }

    .grid-item-2 {
        grid-column: span 1;
    }

    .grid-item-3 {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 30px 80px;
    }

    .grid-item-1-image {
        /* padding: 10px; */
        height: 600px;
        width: 500;
    }

    #image2 img {
        width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
    }

    #caroselControl {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px;
    }

    #cursor1 {
        width: 32px;
        height: 13px;
        margin: 0 16px 0 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    #cursor2 {
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
        margin: 0 17px 0 17px;
        opacity: 0.3;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .grid-item-4 img {
        display: block;
    }

    #item5 {
        display: flex;
    }

    #column1 {
        flex: 1;
    }

    #storeIcons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 10px;
    }
}

/** For Projectors or Higher Resolution Screens (Full HD)**/

/** For 4K Displays (Ultra HD)**/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aa852b7a83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!--KEYSWORDS-->

    <meta name="description"
        content="Enter the market to see goods and services, bargain for convinent prices and make payment in your preferred currency all in just one click.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Online Market - Online Shop">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="">

    <!--Facebook Meta Description -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Aje | Online Market - Online Shop">
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="Enter the market to see goods and services, bargain for convinent prices and make payment in your preferred currency all in just one click.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://https://ajeinc.app/images/logo.png" />
    <title>Aje: Download app to Buy, Sell, and Exchange Goods and Services</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container-0" id="grid-container-0">
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/logo.png" class="logo" height="50" width="100"></a>
        <input class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="hamburger" id="hamburger" for="menu-btn"><span class="navIcon"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- <button onclick="myFunc()" ><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button> -->
        <ul class="navBar" id="navBar">
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#grid-item-3">Features</a></li>
            <li> <a href="/aje/faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#column1">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item-0 ">
            <h1 id="header1">The social market</h1>
            <p id="paragraph1">Enter the market to see goods and services, bargain for convinent prices and make payment
                in your preferred currency all in just one click. We help you connect with potential customers who are
                around you and ready to pay for goods or services.
                Connect by adding a post of your trade. This Product lets you own a wallet with which you can make and
                receive payments. Our wallet helps you convert payments to and from your local currency.
            </p>
            <p id="paragraph1"><a href="/aje/waiting.html"><button type="button" class="btn2">Trade</button></a></p>

        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-1 ">
            <div class="grid-item-1-container">
                <img src="images/grid-item-1-image.png" class="grid-item-1-image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item-2 ">
            <div id="image2">
                <img src="images/grid-item-2-image.png" class="grid-item-2-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-3 " id="grid-item-3">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="two"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="three"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div id="sizer">
                            <h1 id="header1">Features</h1>
                            <div id="carosel">
                                <h2 id="header2">Marketplace</h2>
                                <p id="paragraph1">The Aje community is a social marketplace that allows you see trade
                                    post of other community members that are in close proximity to you. A community
                                    member can search through trade content in finite proximity to them, and by tapping
                                    on
                                    the chat button, a member can engage a trade partner on content of their trade post.
                                    Tapping on the chat button, opens a dialogue between both members of the community.
                                </p>
                                <br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item  two">
                        <div id="sizer">
                            <h1 id="header1">Features</h1>
                            <div id="carosel">
                                <h2 id="header2">Trade</h2>
                                <p id="paragraph1">Once the dialogue is engaged between trade partners, they will have
                                    24hrs to discuss and agree on trade terms. The trade button within the dialogue
                                    prompts a trade agreement contract form, this contract stands as the biding
                                    agreement between trading partners. The trade agreement contract form is completed
                                    by one trade partner and sent to the other party for confirmation. When the trade
                                    agreement contract form is completed and confirmed, the buyers wallet is charged.
                                </p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item three">
                        <div id="sizer"></div>
                        <h1 id="header1">Features</h1>
                        <div id="carosel">
                            <h2 id="header2">Security</h2>
                            <p id="paragraph1">
                                The charged amount can not be paid until both sides have accepted the completion of
                                trade. The seller must confirm delivery and buyer must confirm receipt. Hence trades on
                                the Aje platform are completely secure and are protected from nefarious users and
                                fraudulent products. Trades that are not confirmed as complete by both side will proceed
                                to dispute resolution once specified time of delivery agreed in the contract is reached.
                            </p>
                            <br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-4 ">
            <div><img src="/images/ajeElevatedLogoWhite1024.png" class=""></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5">
            <div id="column1">
                <h5>Download</p>
                    <div id="storeIcons">
                        <div id="appleStoreIcon">
                            <a href="https://testflight.apple.com/join/Wmthbf91">
                                <i class="fa-brands fa-app-store-ios"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="googlePlayIcon">
                            <a
                                href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAwHkSAqwCSFVaAa569KhfH2OJZYdFGn/view?usp=sharing">
                                <i class="fa-brands fa-google-play"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div id="column1">
                <a href="#grid-item-3">
                    <h5>Features</h5>
                </a>
                <a href="#column1">
                    <p>Help Center</p>
                </a>
                <a href="/aje/faq.html">
                    <p>FAQs</p>
                </a>
                <a href="/aje/privacy.html">
                    <p>Privacy</p>
                </a>
                <a href="aje/terms.html">
                    <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="column1">
                <h5>Contact Us</h5>
                <div id="storeIcons">
                    <div id="facebook">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-square"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="twitter">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/ajeapp">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter-square"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="instagram">
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ajeapp/ ">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram-square"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Tel: +90 505 025 9100</p>
                <p>Email: support@ajeinc.app</p>
                <p>Yasam Istanbul Fi life Sitesi 160 Sokak No. 2c/A2 Block Daire 30 Esenyurt/Istanbul. Turkey.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first class of devices will be mobile. So, the first set of styles targeted at mobile devices can be written as is, without being enclosed in `@media (min-width: 375px) { }` Check if this solves the problem.

Also: The CSS Pixels for Samsung S20 are shown as 360px on a initial search.